# Vuetify Is there anyway to hide a v-text-field append-icon

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a form v-textfield with an append-icon to fire a method when clicked
Is there anyway to hide/show conditionally this append-icon ?

Even if I conditionally disable the v-text-field, the append-icon is still clickable...

```
           <v-text-field
            name="email"
            autocomplete="off"
            v-on:input="userEmailChanged"
            :placeholder="$t('lang.views.member.enter_new_email')"
            :readonly="isReadOnly"
            :label="$t('lang.views.home.contactForm.email')"
            v-model="user.email"
            prepend-icon="email"
            append-icon="edit"
            @click:append="editEmail"
            v-validate="'email'"
            data-vv-name="email"
            :error-messages="errors.collect('email')">
          </v-text-field>
```

I can insert a test in the editEmail method, but visually I'd prefer to hide the icon when the editMail method is fired ....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use the prop conditionally, and set the condition to `false` whenever you wanna hide it:

```
<v-text-field 
    :append-icon="showIcon ? 'edit' : undefined"
    @click:append="editEmail" 
></v-text-field>

data: () => ({
    showIcon: true
}),
methods: {
    editMail() {
        // your code code
        this.showIcon = false;
    }
}
```

Revert it to `true` if you want to make it visible again.

---

**Note**: if you want this functionality for clearing the input, there is specific way to do this by using props ([from official example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields#example-icon-events)):

```
<v-text-field 
    clearable 
    clear-icon="mdi-close-circle"
    @click:clear="clearMessage"`
/>

methods: {
    clearMessage () {
        this.message = ''
    },
}
```

Comment: thanks a lo !!! it's working fine ...  see https://codepen.io/erwin16/pen/wxWZOL?editors=1111